# Testing if Button has been released aka User is no longer holding on

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am working on a app that starts a timer when you begin holding the button, when you release from holding the button the timer must stop. I have a Touch Up Inside IBAction that starts the timer, but is there another UI Action I can use to detect that the user is still holding onto the button. I have another method for when it's released. Can you guys help with logistics? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the timer on the control event `UIControlEventTouchDown` and stop it on the control event `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

`UIControlEventTouchDown` will fire once the user "presses down" on the button.
`UIControlEventTouchUpInside` will fire once the user releases the button.

If you want to see what state the button is in, check its `state` property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with iPhone development or objective-c, but most interface API's have an event called 'mouseup' and 'mousedown'. There should be an equivalent for what you're doing.

Comment: There is no mouseup or mousedown event in Xcode, at least not obviously named like that.

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside is your event.

Comment: How can I test that this is being pressed and has not been released. I have been using Touch Up Inside and that is my main question.

Comment: Your title says "Testing if Button has been released aka User is no longer holding on", so I assumed that's what you were looking for.